# How to make bottom nav bar from center cliped

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone I want to clip container from center top.I want to make bottom navigation bar look like below image

[image]

I tried with custom clipper class but not got success.

My Code

```
class TriangleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(0, 0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3750000, 0);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.4218750, size.height * -0.0017500,
        size.width * 0.4300000, size.height * 0.0550000);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.4749625,
        size.height * 0.2266000,
        size.width * 0.5257750,
        size.height * 0.2267500,
        size.width * 0.5708875,
        size.height * 0.0550000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.5790125, 0, size.width * 0.6250000, 0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path_0.close();
    return path_0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Used like this

```
ClipPath(
              clipper: TriangleClipper(),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white60)),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 80,
              ),
            ),
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: Check this one: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar

Answer (score 0):

what about using notch, [notch floating action button](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/bottom-bar-navigation-with-fab/):

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () { },
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    elevation: 2.0,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[],
    ),
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I get error "The named parameter 'notchedShape' isn't defined."

Comment: I got it, it's now "shape" only

Comment: Any way to make transparent fab button, like display map background of bottom nav bar and fab button

Comment: try Scaffold(
          extendBody: true,